# How to set font style to row function in fpdf

Tags: fpdf

I have use fpdf to generate pdf, in that I used Row function to set length and height of row in one line in array, the code is:

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $pdf->SetWidths(array(45,50,45,50));   
    $pdf->SetAligns(array("L"));                        
    $pdf->Row(array('Address',$a->present_address,'Address',$a->permanent_address));
```

I want to Bold the Address and set unbold the $a->present_address, $a->permanent_address  fields,

How I set the font, Please anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using the [Table with MultiCells](http://fpdf.de/downloads/add-ons/table-with-multicells.html) add-on to FPDF. You can extend this add-on to support the desired behavior:

```
class PDF_Styled_MC_Table extends PDF_MC_Table {
    var $styles;

    function SetStyles($styles) {
        $this->styles = $styles;
    }
}
```

Copy the original `Row` method and paste it in your class. Add the following line above the `$this->MultiCell(...)` call:

```
$this->SetFont('', isset($this->styles[$i]) ? $this->styles[$i] : '');
```

Then, in your existing code, change the line that initializes `$pdf` to use your own subclass:

```
$pdf = new PDF_Styled_MC_Table();
```

Finally, add the following line above the line that begins with `$pdf->Row`:

```
$pdf->SetStyles(array('B', '', 'B', '')); // 'B' = bold, '' = regular
```